# SQLITE3 want to find LIKE data within table using long list

Tags: sqlite, sql-like

I have a SQLITE3 table with over 1mil rows and multiple columns, one of which is 'email_address'.
I also have a separate list of about 200k web domains.

I want to find all rows from my table that have email addresses with these domains.
I can figure out how to do it individually with "select * from table where email_address like '%domain';"
But does anyone know how I can do this on a bulk level please?

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing the name of the tables and columns.
Use a join between the 2 tables:

```
SELECT d.domain, e.email_address
FROM domains as d
INNER JOIN emails as e
ON e.email_address LIKE '%' || d.domain
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it without LIKE. Something like

```
select emailAddr,domainName
from email
JOIN domains on substr(emailAddr,instr(emailAddr,'@')+1) = domainName
```

And you can create an index on the domain part of the email address, something like

`CREATE INDEX emailAddr_idx ON email ( substr(emailAddr,instr(emailAddr,'@')+1) )`

I don't know have a big enough data set to test its efficacy/impact.

Answer (score -1):

Was able to get this to work for me:

create table final as select * from alladdresses join alldomains on substr(email_address,instr(email_address,'@')+1) = domain;

Created a new table with all alladdresses info that matched to the domains I had, and added in an extra column of just domains.
Thanks to those who got me on the right path!